# Does the stochastic differential equation $\dot{x}= u'(x)+\sqrt{2D} \xi(t)$ have an analytical solution?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am working with the following SDE: 
$$\dot{x}=  u'(x)+\sqrt{2D} \hspace{1mm} \xi(t)$$

where $u(x)=- \beta|x|$ and the initial conditions is $x=\delta({x-x_0})$ and $\xi(t)$ is a white Gaussian noise.

This process will have a stationary solution at the end, namely: 
$p_0(x)=\frac{D}{2 \beta}exp(-\frac{\beta}{D} |x|)$

(we get this stationary solution by transforming this SDE into a Fokker-Planck equation.)

So my question is, how could I solve this SDE? How could I know whether an analytical solution exists? A very similar equations but with other boundary conditions have solution [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS498/LectureNotes/chp4.pdf), and I was wondering if an analytical solution could also exist for this one.

Any tips or suggested readings would be highly really appreciated.